# Homebrew is extremely slow sometimes and not able to download packages

Tags: installation, homebrew

I am trying to figure out why my Homebrew sometimes takes forever to install a software package in my Mac. I have until now managed to install software like Git and other stuff as well but it has just taken too long time in my opinion.

Last time I tried to install the http-server software and after a while I got some error messages, on which I unfortunately don't have any saved screenshots to show you here.
But bottom line is it could not download and install the software.

Im wondering if it has anything to do with my Homebrew version, like that it's not compatible with my Mac OS version?

This is the software I tried to install (GitHub source):
https://github.com/http-party/http-server

Im using Homebrew version 2.5.1 and Mac OS 10.11.6 (El Capitan)